# How to get the list item and save it to database in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hello I am scraping a website in which I am scraping a div tag and from that "div" tag I am finding all "li" tag. 
My code:

```
response3 = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
soup5 = BeautifulSoup(response3, "html.parser")
companydetail = soup5.find_all("div", id="contact")
for d in companydetail:
    lis = d.find_all('li')
    print (lis)
```

And I am getting result like

```
[<li>

        GUANGZHOU BEGOL HOLDINGS LIMITED

 </li>,
 <li>

              NO. 158 DONGFENG RD.(W).GUANGZHOU,CHINA.

  </li>,
  <li>

        GUANGDONGGUANGZHOU

   </li>,
   <li>

              510170

   </li>,
   <li>

              http://www.begol.com

   </li>]
```

But I want output like:

```
GUANGZHOU BEGOL HOLDINGS LIMITED
NO. 158 DONGFENG RD.(W).GUANGZHOU,CHINA.
GUANGDONGGUANGZHOU
510170
```

After that I want it to save in MySQL database.

Comment: I have tried use this test() but it gives error
    AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting every li element you need to iterate over your lis, since lis is a list of li elements

```
for d in companydetail:
    lis = d.find_all('li')
    for ele in lis:
        print ele.get_text()
```

Comment: it say TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 1):

I think on a resultset, the correct method is get_text().  However, you have more than one element, so you'll have to iterate through lis, call get_text(), and push the result into an array.

Comment: ok get_text() is working. But what if I want to get only one Item from that list suppose only company name

Comment: If your data structure is homogenous, pulling index 0 from the new list you create will get company name.